# Understanding Python's itertools.chain and next

Tags: python, for-loop, iterator, python-itertools, code-translation

I'm trying  to convert a line of Python code to JavaScript, but I have limited Python knowledge and struggle to make sense of it.

Can anyone please try to explain the following line of code? The `point_orientation` function is not important, it just returns True/False.

```py
i_extend = next( ( i for i in itertools.chain(range(i_start+1, len(p)), range(0,i_start+1)) if not point_orientation( p[i-1], p[i], p[(i+1) % len(p)] ) ) )
```

Comment: `chain` is basically list concatenation generalized to arbitrary iterators. `list(chain(list1, list2)) == list1 + list2`.

Comment: I don't know why this is downvoted. This code requires python knowledge to decipher. It looks at two ranges of integers and returns the first one that meets the `if not point_orientation` requirement. Its done with `next` so that the operation stops on the first match. This can be done in javascript with a couple of `for` loops to get the different ranges, and duplicating the test in each.

Answer (score 2):

It means "find the first element `i` in `range(i_start+1, len(p))` or `range(0,i_start+1)` (if the first range doesn't have one) such that `point_orientation( p[i-1], p[i], p[(i+1) % len(p)] )` is false". If there is no such `i`, it will raise an exception.

Here it is in more verbose Python:

```
def check(i):
    return point_orientation(p[i - 1],
                             p[i],
                             p[(i + 1) % len(p)])


def find_i_extend():
    for i in range(i_start + 1, len(p)):
        if not check(i):
            return i

    for i in range(0, i_start + 1):
        if not check(i):
            return i


i_extend = find_i_extend()
```

Answer (score 1):

`chain` stitches two iterators together into one. Here, it's being used to help simulate a closed cycle starting at a particular point. Observe that

```
range(0, len(p)) == chain(range(0, i_start+1), range(i_start+1, len(p))
```

The given code swaps the arguments to `chain`, so that it converts a sequence like `[0,1,2,...,10]` into a sequence like `[5,6,...,10,0,1,...,4]`. The three arguments to the predicate are just adjacent items in the cycle, with `(i+1) % len(p)` doing the wrapping around at the end of the sequence. `next` is just used to get the first element of the resulting sequence.

If you gave up on trying to express this in a one-liner, you might write the more understandable code that follows:

```
n = len(p)
for i in range(i_start + 1, i_start + 1 + n):
    index_before = (i - 1) % n
    index_at = i % n
    index_after = (i+1) % n
    if not point_orientation(p[index_before], p[index_at], p[index_after])
        i_extend = y
        break
```

We iterate over a single range, and do modular arithmetic on the each index inside the loop. If the predicate passes, we set `i_extend` to the current point and break out. Otherwise, we continue the iteration, under the assumption that *one* of the points will eventually succeed.